# Questions about python inheritance and argument lists

Tags: python-2.7, typeerror, attributeerror

First off I am getting this error

```
File "E:\New folder (7)\maingame.py", line 64, in play     print self.introduction AttributeError: 'game' object has no attribute 'introduction'
```

I am not to sure as to what it means because I am pulling the self.introduction from the previous class..

I am also getting an

```
File "E:\New folder (7)\maingame.py", line 96, in <module>
game.play()
TypeError: play() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

error, but can't for the life of me find what argument it is looking for, I simply want it to work.

```
  from random import random

  class place(object):
    def __init__(self, title, description, events):
    self.title = title
    self.description = description
    self.events = events

class event(object):
def __init__(self, probability, message, healthChange):
    self.probability = probability
    self.message = message
    self.healthChange = healthChange

def process(self):
    if random() < self.probability:
        print self.message
        return self.healthChange
    return 0

class textadventure():
def __init__(self):
    super(textadventure, self).__init__()
    self.introduction = """ 
Welcome player, you are a lone traveler in space whom has set out to find glories    beyond measure. 
Unfortunately for you the dread pirate Roberts has attacked. You must defeat him.
    """
    commandDeck = place('Command Deck', "You are now in the command center, here you can drive the ship and fire its weapons.",(
        event(0.7, "The pirate ship fires at you! You take damage to your engines!", -10),
        event(0.2, "One of the pirates manages to beam onto your ship! He shoots you before beaming away!",0),
        ))

    engineRoom = place('Engine Room', "You are now in the main engine room here you can repair damage to the ship",(
        event(0.7, "The pirate ship fires at you! You take damage to your engines!", -10),
        ))

    restQuarters = place('Resting Quarters', "Here you can take a rest and heal your self",(
        event(1.0, 'You are able to patch up your wounds and get back to the battle',0),
        event(0.5, "The pirate ship fires at you! You take damage to your engines!", -10),
        ))

    commandDeck.transitions = (engineRoom, restQuarters),
    engineRoom.transitions = (commandDeck, restQuarters),
    restQuarters.transitions = (commandDeck, engineRoom),

    self.location = commandDeck
pirateHp = 50
class game(object, textadventure):
    def __init__(self):
            super(game, self).__init__()
            self.health = 100
    def location(self):
            if self.location == commandDeck:
                    choice = raw_input('would you like to fire on the enemy ship?')
                    if choice == 'yes':
                            print 'You have hit the pirates!'
                            pirateHp -= 10
                    else: choice == 'no'
            elif self.location == engineRoom:
                    choice = raw_input('Would you like to repair the engines?')
                    if choice == "yes":
                            event(1, "You repair what you can of the engines.", 10)
    def __init__(self):
            self.health = 100
    def play(self, textadventure):
            print textadventure.introduction 

            while True:
                    print (self.location.description)
                    for event in self.location.events:
                            self.health += event.process()
                            if self.health <= 0:
                                    print ("Your ship has been destroyed!")
                                    pause
                                    exit(1)
                    print ('Your ships health is at %d percent' % self.health)
                    self._transition()

    def _transition(self):
            transitions = self.location.transitions
            print ('you can go to: ')
            for (index, transition) in enumerate(transitions):
                    print (index + 1, transition.title)

            choice = int(raw_input('Choose one '))
            if choice == 0:
                    exit(0)
            else:
                    self.location = transitions[choice - 1]

    def pirateShip(Object): 
            if pirateHp == 0:
                    print "You have defeated the pirates! Congradualations!"
                    pause
                    exit(1)

game = game()
game.play(game)
```

Comment: You are at the least going to have to format it properly in the question. And don't forget to put the *full* traceback.

Comment: I re-edited it, thanks.

Not sarcastic genuine thanks

Comment: You should really be asking this as two *separate* questions, since it's (probably) pretty obvious that there are two entirely different problems here.

Answer (score 0):

> 'game' object has no attribute 'introduction'

You should call the **init** of your super class when initializing game. In your current code, textadventure.**init** is never called which is why introduction is never added to textadventure.

Game should also not inherit from object (it does that through textadventure).

```
class game(textadventure):
    def __init__(self):
            super(game, self).__init__()
            self.health = 100

    def play(self):
        print self.introduction
```

Should do the trick.

---

> TypeError: play() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

You never use your `textadventure` argument in play. Removing this should get things working.

Comment: Okay wait I am a little confused, When I call in a previous class, do I also need to call the previous class to the methods in the class?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: Do I need to call the init of textadventure                                                                              here too?                                                                                   def play(self):

Comment: I changed the code above to reflect what I have now. How do I change the play method to make it call in the textadventure class?--- If I need to

Comment: No. You only need to call it in __init__ because otherwise self.introduction will never be assigned.
I edited my answer to include a possible implementation of the play method.

Comment: You seem to have an issue with understanding how inheritance works.
When you say class game(textadventure) you say that game is a child of textadventure. So every method that is defined by textadventure is automatically a part of game. The play method does not need a textadventure attribute.